# Buttons on the left

Tags: gnome, window, 19.10, dconf

I would like to know if there is any way to put all the buttons (max, min and close) to the left since in retouches only puts it in some applications and with the latest version of gnome does not let me. Use ubuntu 19.10 Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open your Ubuntu store (Ubuntu Software).
2. search for tweaks.
3. it's called "gnome-tweaks" install it and then launch it.
4. Click the "Windows" Tab. //it's at the left corner.
5. Scroll to the end you'll find an option called "Placement" choose the "left" option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to intall gnome-tweaks to put buttons to the left.

Launch a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Launch Tweaks, click on "Window Titlebar" and change placement to left.